# How to save PIL images in a loop

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to use a function that itterates over a data frame of image locations and transforms those images then saves them back in the same directory.

Head of the datafram that holds the images

[image: Head of the datafram that holds the images]

The function I defined is as follows:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance

def image_build(img, df):
    for img in df[img]:
        count = 1
        pic = df[img]
        if df['label'].any() == 0:
            im = Image.open(df[img])
            enh = ImageEnhance.Contrast(im)
            im = enh.enhance(1.9)
            im = im.rotate(90)
            im = im.transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
            im = im.resize(224, 224)
            save_dir = 'N:/Users/Howell/Kaggle/X_Ray/chest_xray/train/NORMAL/'
            im.save(save_dir/'new_image_'+count+'.jpeg')
            count += count + 1
            print(count)
```

Then I try to use this function:

```
image_build('image', train_data)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last)
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflowenvironment\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py
> in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    2656             try:
> -> 2657                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)    2658             except KeyError:
> 
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
> 
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
> 
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
> 
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
> 
> KeyError:
> WindowsPath('N:/Users/Howell/Kaggle/X_Ray/chest_xray/train/NORMAL/IM-0580-0001.jpeg')
> 
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> 
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-144-d17ac9ecd789> in <module>
> ----> 1 image_build('image', train_data)
> 
> <ipython-input-143-cf988e867715> in image_build(img, df)
>       2     for img in df[img]:
>       3         count = 1
> ----> 4         pic = df[img]
>       5         if df['label'].any() == 0:
>       6             im = Image.open(df[img])
> 
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflowenvironment\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py
> in __getitem__(self, key)    2925             if self.columns.nlevels
> > 1:    2926                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
> -> 2927             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)    2928             if is_integer(indexer):    2929                 indexer = [indexer]
> 
> C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflowenvironment\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py
> in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)    2657                
> return self._engine.get_loc(key)    2658             except KeyError:
> -> 2659                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))    2660        
> indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance) 
> 2661         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:
> 
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
> 
> pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()
> 
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
> 
> pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in
> pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()
> 
> KeyError:
> WindowsPath('N:/Users/Howell/Kaggle/X_Ray/chest_xray/train/NORMAL/IM-0580-0001.jpeg')
```

I've just discovered Pillow so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Now I'm changed the function to the following and it runs without error but does nothing...not even the `print` statement.

```
def image_build(img, df):
    for img in df[img]:
        count = 1

        if df['label'].any() == 0:
            print('pass_image')
            pic = df[img]
            im = Image.open(pic)
            enh = ImageEnhance.Contrast(im)
            img = enh.enhance(1.9)
            img = im.rotate(90)
            img = im.transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
            img = im.resize(224, 224)
            save_dir = 'N:/Users/Howell/Kaggle/X_Ray/chest_xray/train/NORMAL/'
            img.save(save_dir / 'new_image_'+count+'.jpeg')
            count += 1
```

With help from multiple people, the following runs but only produces one picture and gets stuck printing on count `3`.

from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance

```
def image_build(img, df):
    for index,row in df.iterrows():
        count = 1
        pic = row[img]
        if row['label'] == 0:
            im = Image.open(pic)
            enh = ImageEnhance.Contrast(im)
            im = enh.enhance(1.9)
            im = im.rotate(90)
            im = im.transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
            im = im.resize((750, 500))
            save_dir = Path('N:/Users/Howell/Kaggle/X_Ray/chest_xray/train/NORMAL/')
            count2 = str(count)
            im.save(save_dir / str('new_image_'+count2+'.jpeg'))
            count += count + 1
            print(count)
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: Try this count += 1 instead of Count += count +1 both are different because if you want your count to be incremented once each iteration then you should use count+=1

Comment: Thanks @ChetanVashisth but still the same error.

Comment: @Jordon Please check the path you have defined for your images? Just to be sure about that

Comment: I did.  When I take the image sequence out of the loop and run it on `train_data['image'][0]` in the `Image.open()` command, it works.

Comment: try the code below if it works bro @Jordon

Answer (score 1):

You use the same variable img again

```
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance

def image_build(img, df):
    for index,row in df.iterrows():
        count = 1
        pic = row[img]
        if row['label'] == 0:
            im = Image.open(pic)
            enh = ImageEnhance.Contrast(im)
            im = enh.enhance(1.9)
            im = im.rotate(90)
            im = im.transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
            im = im.resize(224, 224)
            save_dir = 'N:/Users/Howell/Kaggle/X_Ray/chest_xray/train/NORMAL'
            im.save(f'{save_dir}/new_image_{count}.jpeg'))
            count += count + 1
            print(count)
```

Comment: Thank you.  I got `TypeError: 'WindowsPath' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: using the same var img doesn't matter bro i have executed the same code that i have posted and it does run without any error

Comment: ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-330-d17ac9ecd789> in <module>
----> 1 image_build('image', train_data)

<ipython-input-329-1bf389a1a05c> in image_build(img, df)
      5         count = 1
      6         pic = row[img]
----> 7         if row['label'].any() == 0:
      8             im = Image.open(pic)
      9             enh = ImageEnhance.Contrast(im)

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'any'

Comment: --> 15             im.save(save_dir/'new_image_'+count+'.jpeg')
     16             count += count + 1
     17             print(count)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Ok @ SmartManoj.  I am getting the loop to run but it's only producing one image to the folder.  See my edits above.

Comment: Thanks SmartManoj.  I figured it out. See my answer.  Take the `count = 1` outside the `for` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it works:

```
def image_build(img, df):
    count = 1  #  define count here so that it do not get intialised for each iteration
    for img in df[img]:
        pic = df[img]
        if df['label'].any() == 0:
            im = Image.open('your_image_path')
            enh = ImageEnhance.Contrast(im)
            img = enh.enhance(1.9)
            img = im.rotate(90)
            img = im.transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
            img = im.resize((224, 224))
            save_dir = 'your path'
            img.save(save_dir + 'new_image_'+'1'+'.jpeg')
            count += 1
```

Comment: `KeyError: WindowsPath('N:/Users/Howell/Kaggle/X_Ray/chest_xray/train/PNEUMONIA/person1286_bacteria_3249.jpeg')`

Comment: which i'm not sure what it chose that path because it's corresponding `label` is 1 not 0.

Comment: You want to perform the diffrent operations on images and then save them back in the same directory with a new name right?? That's what exactly you want to do?

Comment: Try using this link it will help you  https://www.sitepoint.com/manipulating-images-with-the-python-imaging-library/

Comment: I think it may be how i'm doing the `if` statement.  See the updated question.  Now it runs with  no error but does not product any pics.

Comment: same error.  This is frustrating.  Thanks for sticking with this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193693/discussion-between-chetan-vashisth-and-jordan).

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  I finally got it!  Move the count before the `iterrows()`

Edited

```
from PIL import Image, ImageEnhance

def image_build(img, df):
    count = 1
    for index,row in df.iterrows():
        pic = row[img]
        if row['label'] == 0:
            im = Image.open(pic)
            enh = ImageEnhance.Contrast(im)
            im = enh.enhance(1.9)
            im = im.rotate(90)
            im = im.transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
            im = im.resize((750, 500))
            save_dir = Path('N:/Users/Howell/Kaggle/X_Ray/chest_xray/train/NORMAL/')
            count2 = str(count)
            im.save(save_dir + str('new_image_'+count2+'.jpeg'))
            count += count + 1
            print(count)
        else:
            pass
```

Answer (score -2):

I think this is the problem with the path of the file. replace / with \(double backslash) or \