# Only the last displayed PIL image by Image.show() is saved

Tags: python, for-loop, python-imaging-library

I have been trying to save images to a specific directory generated from a list shown below. I am able to generate the bitmap images as displayed by img.show() but when I try to save it to the stipulated directory it only saves one of the images that being the last one. I have searched through various other similar issues with no added help to my problem except for that in https://stackoverflow.com/a/56237732/13648455 which helped a bit. I probably missing something small in my code. I am using Jupyter notebook to run my code.

```
arrays = [[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0,
       1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0,
       1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

arr = np.array(arrays)

def image_creator(image_array):
    count = 0
    image_array = image_array.reshape(2, 51)
    img = Image.new('1', (2, 51))
    pixels = img.load()
    new_list = image_array.tolist()
    
    for i in range(img.size[0]):
        
        for j in range(img.size[1]):
            
            pixels[i, j] = new_list[i][j]
            
            save_dir = '{Insert Directory}'
    
    img.show()
    
    img.save(f'{save_dir}/Example_{count}.bmp')
    count += 1
    
    
    return img


x = map(image_creator, arr)
print(list(x))
```

Comment: Every time you call `image_creator()`, you set `count` to zero - so all of the images get saved with the exact same filename.  Make that a global variable, initialized *outside* of the function, so that its value is persistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting editions of answer that worked as mentioned by jasonharper (comment above).

```
count = 0

def img_creation(image_array):
    global count
```